# consulta con mongoose no devuelve el subdocumento

Tags: nodejs, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy haciendo un sistema de publicaciones con comentarios, estoy utilizando `moongoose`, `nodejs` y `typescript` para el backend, este es mi modelo de publicaciones:

```
const esquema_publicaciones: SchemaDefinition = {
  texto: {type: String, required: false},
  usuario: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "usuarios" },
  likes: [ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "usuarios" } ],
  comments: [ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "comentarios" } ],
  file: {type: [String], required: false},
};
```

1. El campo `texto` guarda el texto de la publicación.
2. El campo `usuario` se guarda el usuario que creo la publicación, hace referencia al modelo de usuario.
3. El campo `likes` guarda a los usuarios que likearon la publicación, hace referencia al modelo de usuarios.
4. El campo `comments` es un array que contiene los id's de los comentarios, hacen referencia al modelo `comentarios`.
5. El campo `file` simplemente contiene las url's de las imágenes que se suben.

Este es mi modelo de datos de los comentarios:

```
const esquema_comentarios: SchemaDefinition = {
  texto: {type: String, required: true},
  usuario: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "usuarios" },
  likes: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "usuarios" }],
};
```

1. El campo `texto` contiene el texto del comentario.
2. El campo `usuario` es el que contiene los datos del usuario que comento la publicación.
3. El campo `likes` guarda a los usuarios que likearon el comentario, hace referencia al modelo de usuarios.

este es mi controlador para guardar las publicaciones:

```
export const Publicar = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { user, body }: any = req
  const img: string[] = [];
  const images: any = req.files
  for await (const file of images) {
    const routeimg = path.join(file.path);
    img.push(routeimg);
  }
  try {
    const new_publication = new Publicacion({
      texto: body.texto,
      usuario: user._id,
      file: img
    });
    const publi: IPublicaciones = await new_publication.save();
    usuario.publicaciones.addToSet(publi._id);
    await usuario.save();
    return res.status(200).json({ message: "Publicado con exito." });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(500).json({ message: "Ocurrio un error al publicar." });
  }
};
```

1. Desde el `req` desestructuro el `user` que me retorna `passport` y el `body`.
2. Las imágenes ya llegan listas para guardar, solamente tengo que retocar la ruta y ya.
3. Se crea la publicación y dependiendo de si salió bien retorno un `200` y guardo el id de la publicación en el modelo de usuario en la sección publicaciones que hace referencia a las publicaciones, de lo contrario `500`.

Este es el controlador para agregar comentarios:

```
export const Comentar = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { user }: any = req
  const { texto, publicacionId } = req.body
  try {
    const comentario: IComentarios = new Comentario({
      texto,
      usuario: user._id
    })
    const comment = await comentario.save()
    const publication: IPublicaciones | any = await Publicaciones.findById(publicacionId)
    publication?.comments.addToSet(comment._id)
    await publication.save()
    return res.status(200).json({message: 'Comentario enviado.'})
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    return res.status(500).json({message: 'Intentalo mas tarde'})
  }
};
```

1. El body recibe el texto de el comentario y el id de la publicación.
2. Primero creo el comentario, y luego en la publicación guardo el id del comentario, y dependiendo de si salió bien envío un status `200` de lo contrario un `500`.

Después de mostrar los modelos y controladores, viene el problema, cuando hago una petición a la ruta `all_post`, me devuelve las publicaciones, hago el `populate` para poder mostrar la publicación y los datos de usuario para que el cliente vea quien lo publico, hasta ahí todo bien, cuando creo un comentario se crea bien, no hay problema tampoco, pero en la misma ruta `all_post` en el controlador hago varios `populate` además del usuario, también quiero los comentarios, entonces con un simple `populate("comments")` este me devuelve los datos de los comentarios, perfecto, pero el error es cuando quiero los datos de ese usuario, intenté con un `populate("comments.usuario")` pero de esta forma solamente me devuelve los ids de los comentarios.

```
export const Publicaciones = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { user }: any = req;
  const users = [user._id];
  try {
    const usr: IUsuario | null | any = await Usuario.findById(user._id);
    for await (let element of usr?.amigos) {
      users.push(element);
    }
    const publicaciones: IPublicaciones[] = await Publicacion.find({ usuario: { $in: users } })
    .populate("usuario")
    .populate("likes")
    .populate("comments.usuario") //esto no funciona
    .sort({ createdAt: 1 })
    return res.status(200).json(publicaciones);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return res.status(500).json({ message: "Intentalo mas tarde." });
  }
};
```

Necesitaría poder obtener los datos de esos usuarios, cuando pido al backend las publicaciones con el populate `.populate("comments.usuario")` me las devuelve así:

```
  {
    likes: [],
    comments: [
      6046513d812145219491e171
    ],
    file: [],
    _id: 60464f747f35db14783ccbcc,
    texto: publicacion desde insomnia,
    usuario: 60464dedc5327719ecce5232,
    createdAt: 2021-03-08T16:23:16.316Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-03-08T16:30:53.582Z,
  }
```

Y cuando pido con el populate `.populate("comments")` me los devuelve así:

```
  {
    likes: [],
    comments: [
      {
        likes: [],
        _id: 6046513d812145219491e171,
        texto: comentario desde insomnia,
        usuario: 60464dedc5327719ecce5232,
        createdAt: 2021-03-08T16:30:53.553Z,
        updatedAt: 2021-03-08T16:30:53.553Z,
      }
    ],
    file: [],
    _id: 60464f747f35db14783ccbcc,
    texto: publicacion desde insomnia,
    usuario: 60464dedc5327719ecce5232,
    createdAt: 2021-03-08T16:23:16.316Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-03-08T16:30:53.582Z,
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Debes de hacerlo por etapas para que funcione:

```js
const publicaciones: IPublicaciones[] = await Publicacion.find({
    usuario: {
      $in: users
    }
  })
  .populate("usuario")
  .populate("likes")
  .populate("comments") 
  .populate("comments.usuario")
```

## Edición.

Necesitas hacer deep population de esta manera:

```
 .populate({
        path: "comments",
        populate: {
          path: "usuario",
          select: "nombre", //Este campo solo te traera las propiedades que pongas aqui como un string. Te recomiendo que solo traigas lo que necesites. 
        },
      })
```

Con esto conseguiras lo que quieres. Tuve que hacer un pequeño ajuste en tu controlador para guardar los id en comments TS.

```
const comentario: IComentarios = new Comentario({
      texto,
      usuario: Types.ObjectId(_id),
    })
```

Comment: esto me devuelve los comentarios pero el usuario no lo retorna, en el campo usuario me muestra el id de ese usuario nomas

Comment: Como exportaste tu modelo de usuario?. Puedes poner la linea donde haces el mongoose.model("usuario",UsuarioSchema)?

Comment: de la siguiente manera `export default model<IUsuario>("usuarios", Usuario);` quieres que suba el modelo de usuario? no lo veía necesario pero si así lo quieres...

Comment: prueba con `.populate("comments.usuario", undefined, "usuarioss") `

Comment: me sigue devolviendo lo mismo el usuario se sigue mostrando así `usuario: "604672290855180bc8d5dcfd"`

Comment: Puedes subir una parte del codigo a git y compartirlo?. Solo replicar la parte que no funciona. Y solo por descartar, existe ese id?

Comment: lo verifique y si, ese id existe, y el repositorio esta [aca](https://github.com/Enzo-taiel/backend)

Comment: Edite mi respuesta. Revísala por favor.

Answer (score 2):

Aunque ya se me han adelantado en la respuesta, trataré de explicar el porqué del problema y su solución.

**PROBLEMA**

Según lo que puedo entender de la pregunta, deseas hacer una búsqueda en la base de datos para los documentos de la colección de publicaciones, y realizar un proceso de poblado ([`populate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.htm)) de [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com), sobre los siguientes campos:

- `usuario`
- `likes`
- `comments`
- `comments.usuario` (es un campo que tiene una referencia a la colección de usuarios)

Sin embargo, estás intentando esto:

```js
const publicaciones: IPublicaciones[] = await Publicacion
  .find({ usuario: { $in: users } })
  .populate("usuario")
  .populate("likes")
  .populate("comments.usuario") //esto no funciona
  .sort({ createdAt: 1 });
```

Lo cual claramente no funciona por una razón o motivo muy particular que trataré de exponer con detalle en la solución.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es usar un proceso conocido como [`deep populate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#deep-populate) o *población profunda*.

Para poder entender este proceso debemos partir por el hecho de que el método [`populate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) se aplica sobre los documentos creados a partir de un [Modelo](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) de datos. Cada Modelo es a su vez creado por un [Esquema](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html).

Es precisamente en este esquema donde podemos guardar una referencia especial (sólo disponible en Mongoose y no persistida a MongoDB), de un campo hacia documentos de otro modelo de datos (en la misma colección o en una diferente).

Esto significa que si tienes la siguiente referencia, en tu modelo de publicaciones:

```js
comments: [
  { type: ObjectId, ref: "Comment" }
]
```

cuando haces el llamado al método `populate()` efectivamente se llenarán los datos del documento de comentarios al que hace referencia el campo `comments`. Pero sólo poblará los campos del documento que existen en la colección.

Entre los campos que existen en dicha colección, se encuentra el campo `usuario`, pero en MongoDB sólo se guarda el valor del campo `_id` del documento de la colección de `usuarios` al que apunta dicho comentario, nada más. La referencia al Modelo de Usuario la guarda Mongoose, no MongoDB. Es por ello que esto:

```js
populate("comments.usuario")
```

no hace el poblado del campo usuario, porque el modelo de Publicación **desconoce** la referencia en el campo `comments.usuario`, ya que dicha referencia es del modelo de comentarios y no del modelo de publicaciones.

**Deep populate**

Es en este momento que entra en juego el poblado profundo o *deep populate*, ya que en el mismo se hace una petición de poblado de un campo referenciado dentro de un método `populate`.

Para el caso relacionado con tu pregunta se tiene que el poblado profundo se hace sobre el campo `usuario` del comentario que se está poblando para la solicitud sobre el modelo de Publicación.

Esto se escribe en Mongoose de la siguiente forma:

```js
.populate({
  path: "comments", // <- campo de la publicación que deseamos poblar
  populate: {
    path: "usuario", // <- campo del comentario que deseamos poblar
    select: "_id nombre correo ..." // <- campos que deseo traer de la colección de usuarios
  }
  select: "_id usuario ..." // <- campos que deseo traer de la colección de comentarios
})
```

Esta sería la forma en la que puedes traer los campos de la colección de usuarios haciendo una consulta a la colección de publicaciones poblando el campo `comments` y poblando a su vez el campo `usuario`.

**Nota**

Veo que en tus esquemas usas las siguientes referencias:

```js
usuario: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "usuarios" },
likes: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "usuarios" }],
```

Recuerda que las referencias de Mongoose son un aspecto del ODM y no se persisten en la base de datos. Por lo tanto el campo `ref` en un Esquema de Mongoose, debe referirse al nombre de un Modelo y no al nombre de una colección de MongoDB.

Si tu modelo de datos se llama `Usuario` (nótese que se usa primera letra en mayúscula), la referencia en Mongoose debe apuntar a dicho modelo de datos:

```js
usuario: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Usuario" },
```

Y el modelo de datos debes llamarlo de esa forma al instanciarlo con `mongoose.model`:

```js
const UsuarioModel = mongoose.model("Usuario", UsuarioSchema);
```

Esta es la forma en que Mongoose conecta (relaciona) documentos almacenados en las colecciones de MongoDB.